# Magento 1. Set customer attribute based on (max) order attribute values

Tags: attributes, customer

we want to store some meta/customer attributes dynamically based on order data. Per customer we would like to store the brand attribute that was sold most and store the size attribute that was sold most.

Support a customer has 3 orders with products

```
Order    Item1                     item2                     item3
12345    Shoe (brand XX, size 41)  Shoe (brand YY, size 41)  Shoe (brand XX, size 43)
45678    Shoe (brand AA, size 41)  Shoe (brand XX, size 41)  Shoe (brand XX, size 43)
```

So this customer has a preference for: size = 41 and Brand = XX

Now we would like to run a query (or via code) that updates this customer (custom) attributes with size = 41 and Brand = XX -- actually do it for all customers.

**Question**: Can this be done via a simple query (using max) or magento model with code or extension? Maybe some example already exist.

(fyi. we need thos because we link to external datasources that can only communicate customer attributes)

Comment: You can do this things when order place.

Comment: well but thats too late ;) we now want to do this in batch/cron via query or similar